# XNA terrain builder Problems

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, terrain

I am working from this tutorial and I had some issues with it. 
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_from_file.php
I used the code at the bottom of the page and I build and it gave me this error

```
EmbedXnaFrameworkRuntimeProfile:
Skipping target "EmbedXnaFrameworkRuntimeProfile" because all output files up-to-date with respect to the input files.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702   nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;WINDOWS  /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Avatar.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Video.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Xact.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\x86\Debug\TerrainBuilder1.exe /resource:obj\x86\Debug\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.RuntimeProfile.txt,Microsoft.Xna.Framework.RuntimeProfile /target:winexe /win32icon:Game.ico Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Program.cs Game1.cs "C:\Users\Kenshin\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

Ok that looks really horrible.

What I am doing is running this in XNA 4.0 and I think this comes from XNA 3.0 I dont think there should be any problem with that but just in case. 
Thanks for any help with this

Comment: I don't see any errors. Its just skipping a target.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an XNA 4 Terrain tutorial that uses heightmap based terrain like Reimers, I've created one that also uses a QuadTree, LOD and Culling.  My culling uses a technique to project the view frustrum to 2D space rather than using a bounding frustrum and it greatly increased my performance.  I haven't finished the final part of the tutorial yet because I'm seeing some small issues with the culling when the view distance is set too great that I haven't had time to take a look at yet, but the series is finished from loading the heightmap clear through rendering, culling and LOD.  It's lengthy and wordy as I've tried to explain everything as I went:

http://www.dustinhorne.com/page/XNA-Terrain-Tutorial-Table-of-Contents.aspx

I've also converted the code and have it working with Silverlight 5 XNA but I'm working on a paging system to make it more feasible since the terrain size is much smaller (Silverlight 5 uses the Reach profile and 16-bit indices which limits the overall size of the terrain chunk).  Once I get time to work on that again I'll be posting it as well.